# Error: DefaultOperationDescriptor@2b878eea already available in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, synchronization, runtime-error

**Failed to complete Gradle Execution**

When I try to Sync Gradle with Project Files, the error mentioned below appears

Android Studio version that I am using is 3.0.1, Gradle Build 4.1-all.zip

FYI, I have already tried ->Build->Clean Project and Invalidate Cache & Restart and one more thing is that there is no error in my code.

**Message Error:**

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
>   Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause:
>   Operation org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.events.DefaultOperationDescriptor@86028ba already available.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
>
> Information:1 error
>
> Information:0 warnings

**But When I try to Run on my Emulator**

The error below appears

**Message Error At Run Time**

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   E:\Android Game App\app\build.gradle
>   Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':Android Game App:app'.
>   Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Due to a limitation of Gradle new variant-aware dependency management, loading the Android Gradle plugin in different class loaders leads to a build error.
>        This can occur when the buildscript classpaths that contain the Android Gradle plugin in sub-projects, or included projects in the case of composite builds, are set differently.
>        To resolve this issue, add the Android Gradle plugin to only the buildscript classpath of the top-level build.gradle file.
>        In the case of composite builds, also make sure the build script classpaths that contain the Android Gradle plugin are identical across the main and included projects.
>        If you are using a version of Gradle that has fixed the issue, you can disable this check by setting android.enableBuildScriptClasspathCheck=false in the gradle.properties file.
>        To learn more about this issue, go to https://d.android.com/r/tools/buildscript-classpath-check.html.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 16s
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Nothing found on Google! Any help would be highly encouraged???

Comment: I really need an urgent help in this regard...! Please

Comment: could you add your build.gradle files? which version of android gradle plugin are you using? how many modules you have?. i face the same problem and solved it. but need more info.

Comment: @ffgiraldez I didn't got any help unfortunately. So, I have to bear the loss and downgrade my Android Studio from 3.0.1 to 2.3.3, which is annoying. But, this error disappeared after that. That's the only thing I did by myself.

Answer (score 4):

The key to the problem is this line. Maybe due to a project.all in root build.gradle or you are using composite builds.

```
This can occur when the build script classpaths that contain the Android Gradle plugin in sub-projects, 
or included projects in the case of composite builds, are set differently.
```

that mean in all yours build.gradle you have more than one this line

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.y.z"
    }
}
```

what this means is that with the introduction of Android Gradle Plugin 3.Y.Z and the new way of [handling dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations), 
if you mix in the same project 2 projects with different plugin version (one with a 2.3 and other with 3.0.1) you will get dragons while compiling.

And this error it's a way to force developer to check it and opt-out once detected and solved.

how to solve it, first ensure you don't use a android gradle plugin below 3.0.1 and use the new dependencies configurations, and add this property on every gradle.properties you have.

```
android.enableBuildScriptClasspathCheck=false
```

with that you can now compile

one example could be found at [realm sample repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/build.gradle) they use a allprojects block that include android gradle plugin on every module. and solve it adding previus gradle property at root [gradle.properties](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/gradle.properties)

Comment: Well! You highlighted the right bug of this problem. It was actually happening due to the composite build. !!!

Comment: I use composite builds also, and the solution was add the android.enableBuildScriptClasspathCheck=false on every gradle.properties, in the included one and also in the project that use the composite builds

Comment: should be great if you mark my answer as the solution